# JQuery - Search some part of the string and using replaceWith on that string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this sentence

```
 Tom __ English.
```

I want to find the `__` part and change it to something. How will I do that?

My sample code:

```
  var $str = 'Tom __ English.',
      $new = $str.match('__');

  $new.replaceWith('is');
```

My wanted output:

```
  Tom is English.
```

Comment: Why would you try to use jQuery for that? Use built-in Javascript string methods like `replace`

Comment: How bout some sample then sir? :)

Comment: Your sample code should already do that. The twist, is that it's throwing you a curve. In your code, it needs to capture the object to be replaced first. In this case '$new'. The 'is' is added in the replaceWith function on the $new object. So what ever $new is, will get replaced with the contents of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `replace` by pure JS

```js
var str = 'Tom __ English.';

console.log(str.replace("__", "is"))
```

Hope it helps